# How to prevent field length errors breaking a script when writing to a database in Coldfusion?

Tags: mysql, csv, coldfusion, import, insert

I'm trying to create a CSV import (using Coldfusion8) into my database.

The CSV file is first parsed into a Coldfusion array (`"x"`, done using [this UDF](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2041-UPDATE-Parsing-CSV-Data-Files-In-ColdFusion-With-csvToArray-.htm)), which I'm then feeding into a temporary table for validation before actually submitting it to the database using a JSON mapping for which CSV-columns to import).

Everything is working fine except field lengths... which still throw errors.

Right now I'm importing like this:

```
...
<cfif variables.c_comp NEQ "">
, <cfqueryparam value = "#x[variables.c_comp]#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50">
</cfif>
...
```

With `x` being the CSV-row being parsed and `variables.c_comp` being the JSON map column number for the specified field.

My problem is, if the user submits a field with length 51 characters, the whole import fails.

**Question:**
Is there a way to import the first 50 characters and NOT throw an error? Or maybe set a flag only.

Thanks for inputs!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the Left() function to trim it to the maxlength

```
<cfqueryparam value = "#Left(x[variables.c_comp], 50)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50">
```